# How do I make browserify ONLY include the list of files I EXPLICITLY specify?

Tags: node.js, browserify

I've been trying to optimize my browserify build. Basically, I only want to include a subset of my server files in my bundle. What I really want to do is hand-pick the files that I want it to include, as I have a pretty large project. Browserify seems to really like to follow requires very eagerly and put them all in my bundle. I know I can tell it to exclude/ignore files, but it's really annoying to have to explicitly exclude almost every file in my project.

Is there some way to make browserify NOT follow requires as its default behavior and include ONLY the files that I tell it to?

Answer (score 1):

Browserify just have [`exclude` and `ignore`](https://github.com/substack/browserify-handbook#ignoring-and-excluding) by default, to control which modules are put in the package.

To implement this functionality the best way would probably be to do a PR to browserify. If you want to do it just in your own project one way is to create the Browserify object:

```
var browserify = require('browserify');
```

create the functionality for include (just copying what they do for exclude) and then overwrite the [`_createDeps`](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify/blob/7f8030563e89116a8a1d53feb8037006dc5c31e3/index.js#L422). Maybe just copying the whole function except for the [part](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify/blob/7f8030563e89116a8a1d53feb8037006dc5c31e3/index.js#L475) where it chooses what files to include.

Comment: Hmmmm... I would think that this is a common problem / feature request. Kind of strikes me odd that this behavior isn't implemented (yet). I can't be the only one with this issue and would want to ignore all files by default.

Comment: I can't say anything about that. I just know that it doesn't include that functionality. I hacked pretty much on it, trying to use it in another way on another project. Maybe some of the alternatives like webpack has the functionality.